# URL Encode in Windows Batch Script

Tags: python, linux, windows, batch-file

I have a Windows batch script that I use to do quick Google searches.  However, I can't figure out how to generically encode special characters.  Like if I try to search for C#, the pound sign breaks it.  Here is my code:

```
SET q="https://www.google.com/#q=%*"
SET q=%q: =+%
chrm %q%
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: This is a no brainer if you just step back and think about it.  Do a Google search for **C#** and then look at the url that Google kicks back in your browser.

Comment: @Squashman I think he wants to encode **all** special characters, and doing that manually would take forever

Comment: Dennis is correct. I know how to find a character encoding manually.  npocmaka nailed it and I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without installing any external tools:

```
@echo off
setlocal


set "string=gibberish+?blahblah@"


:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=)));""



:: FOR /F does not need pipe
for /f %%N in (
  '%beginJS% encodeURIComponent("%string%") %endJS%'
) do set encoded=%%N
echo %string% -^> %encoded%
```

Comment: VERY nice! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: if url contains "=" char ,it does not work

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is a good way to do that directly in a Windows bat script.  Python is a great solution for some heavier things like that, and it is cross platform which is always nice.  Since you are in Windows, you could probably write a powershell script to do it.  However, here is a Python 3 script I wrote which I think does what you are looking for.

```py
import sys
import subprocess
import urllib.parse

browser = sys.argv[1]
browserParms = sys.argv[2]

queryString = " ".join(sys.argv[3:])
queryString = urllib.parse.quote(queryString)
url = "https://www.google.com/#q=" + queryString

subprocess.Popen([browser, browserParms, url])

sys.exit()
```

Here is a native script for Linux where you can set up your specifics.  You could do something very similar in a windows batch file. I named it goog (with no extension because that would be too much to type :) )

```bash
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/justin/Dropbox/MyFiles/Programs/CrossPlatform/Python3/GoogleSearch.py "firefox" "-new-window" "$@"
```

Make sure your native script location is in $PATH.  Execute like this from Terminal or Run A Command.

```
goog i like turtles
```

Comment: That is a pretty good solution, but I had to mark npocmaka's solution as accepted because it is really more what I am looking for.  I don't want to install python.