# Windows (command line) tool to convert non-ascii characters to HTML numeric codes

Tags: html, windows, batch-file, unicode, ascii

I'm searching for a simple **windows** (command line) tool which converts all non-ascii characters in a file to HTML numeric codes.

I found [uni2ascii](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/uni2ascii.1.html) for linux, which does exactly what we want, but we need a tool for windows.
In uni2ascii, the corresponding command would be:

```
uni2ascii -a H input.json -q
```

Example input:

```
{"title":"Профил"}
```

Output:

```
{"title":"&#x041F;&#x0440;&#x043E;&#x0444;&#x0438;&#x043B;"}
```

Comment: If it is in Ubuntu I would assume it is also in WSL.  Did a quick Google search and it appears uni2ascii has been ported to Windows by several developers.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes, the script in that answer answers my question. I'm just wondering why I didn't find it...

Comment: I thing winthout external tools you can use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083043/).

Comment: @Daemon-5 - No, it appears that that "solution" is actually for going in the other direction - i.e., you HAVE URLEncoded/HTMLEntity, and you want the actual character; what the querent is saying is that he HAS actual character and WANTS URLEncoded/HTMLEntity.

Comment: My mistake. I gave the wrong link. It should be [mshta-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186560/)