# URL Decode in Windows Batch Script

Tags: url, decode

I'm trying to decode an URL using a batch script.
I've found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187347/2406740) to encode it.

I tried to decode using "decodeURI" function for javascript, but it doesn't work.

Input is

```
https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FSomeProfile%2Fstatus%2F1234567890
```

Output should be

```
https://twitter.com/SomeProfile/status/1234567890
```

If I use that script, output is:

```
httpsAFFtwitter.comFSomeProfileFstatusF1234567890
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Editing to improve comprehension:

This is the code I'm using:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "string=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FSomeProfile%2Fstatus%2F1234567890"

:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=)));""


:: FOR /F does not need pipe
for /f %%N in (
  '%beginJS% decodeURI("%string%") %endJS%'
) do set encoded=%%N
echo %string% -^> %encoded%
```

How to get the correct URL without "%" symbols?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Modify input to `https%%3A%%2F%%2Ftwitter.com%%2FSomeProfile%%2Fstatus%%2F1234567890` - see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#percent

Comment: Thank you, @JosefZ, your suggestion works fine. Question answered and solved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JosefZ, I could see what was wrong.

Input must escape "%" symbol.

It's working now.

Thank you, JosefZ.